# Getting the value out of a key in a JSON response

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, key

How do I get the value of the key "exists" from the json response? I have previously tried

```
$json['data']['exists']
and 
$json['data']->exists
```

but it's not working. If I print_r the response this is what is being printed:

```
Array ( [exists] => )
```

My Current code:

```
<?php

    //Initialize cURL.
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set the URL that you want to GET by using the CURLOPT_URL option.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url');

    //Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER so that the content is returned as a variable.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //Execute the request.
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $jsonData = json_decode($data,true);

    print_r($jsonData['data']);

    //Close the cURL handle.
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Can you show the JSON coming back (`echo  $data;` will do).

Comment: @NigelRen All it returns is "Array"

Comment: Is this just after the line `$data = curl_exec($ch);`?

Comment: It's right after the json_decode

Comment: No - echo the value being returned by `curl_exec()`.  This is before any decoding!

Comment: {"status":200,"status_message":"Success","data":{"exists":false}} is what I get

Comment: The value is there - but false tends not to display - see duplicate for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s because the « exist » value is false. This is the reason why you’ve got an empty value in $jsonData[‘data’][‘exist’].

You will never see on printing a Boolean value ! 
It’s 1 for true and empty for false.

You can send false value as a string : ´false’